# Custom Page Template in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, fopen

I am using a Custom Page Template in Wordpress. I followed these steps to make it:

1. Duplicated page.php file in the /wp-content/themes/themename/ directory to another file called, submit.php
2. Inserted the Template Name in the PHP code at the starting. I am unable to post the snippet here, stackoverflow is not displaying it.
3. Now it shows up in the wp-admin panel under Page Templates.

I have an HTML form on the Custom Page of Wordpress. The PHP will read the data entered by the end user in the text area and write it to a file stored on the server.

All goes well as long as I write this data to a file this way:

```
$fp=fopen("filename.txt","w") or die("Can't open the file");
```

However, as a result of this file will be available in the path:

```
http://sitename.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/themename/filename.txt
```

So, it will store the data read from the HTML form in the current directory. Instead I want to write this to a file stored in another location. Let's say:

```
http://sitename.com/wordpress/files/filename.txt
```

to do this, I modified the code this way:

```
$fp=fopen("../../../files/filename.txt","w") or die("Can't open the file");
```

The PHP script dies with the error message, could not open the file.

I tried writing the output to **wp-content/uploads** directory as follows.

```
$filename="../../uploads/".$cartype.".txt";
$fp=fopen($filename,"w") or die("can't open the file");
```

It Gives the error: can't open the file.

$cartype is just a value that is read via the HTML Form input.

I have set the permissions for the uploads folder to 777 already.

I tried this as well:

```
$filename="/wp-content/uploads/".$cartype.".txt";
$fp=fopen(ABSPATH.$filename,"w") or die("can't open the file");
```

It again gives the error: can't open the file.

Please note that, I am writing data into the file later this way:

```
fwrite($fp,$data)
```

Also, once I am able to do this, I would like to restrict the permissions to the "files" directory so that only the wordpress admin can read the files in that directory using FTP or similar alternative.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could `chmod 777 /path/to/wordpress/files/` however, I would put them in `wp-content/uploads` since that's probably already writeable.

Comment: I tried wp-content/uploads and still get the same error that it cannot open the file. Please mention the complete syntax for fopen. How do I mention the path? The permissions of the uploads folder are set to 777.

Comment: If the permissions were 777 you wouldn't get an permission errors. Try using `ABSPATH . '/wp-content/uploads/filename.txt` as your path.

Comment: I used ABSPATH and it still gives the error, can't open the file. I have updated my original post. I tried using the path: ../../uploads and now it does not give me the error, can't open the file and but neither does it write any output file in the upload directory either.